# In a CordaR3 transaction can I consume a state known only by one party?

Tags: kotlin, transactions, blockchain, corda

I have 2 parties (A and B)
In the same transaction I want to:
    Consume an inputState known only by party A,
    Produce an outputState known only by party B,
    Produce an outputState known both by party A and B

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding it is not feasible. Let's write down what you want to achieve:

1. Consume an InputState known only by party A
2. Produce an OutputState known only by party B
3. Produce an OutputState known only by party A and B

I think these points make this not achievable:

1. If Party A initiates a flow, then it should somehow query OutputState which is only known by Party B. This state is not in Party A's vault for sure and is not in dependencies as per the requirement "OutputState known only by party B).
2. If Party B initiates a flow, then it should somehow query or initialize IntputState known only by Party A, which is not in Party B's vault or is not in its dependencies and this statement in general contradicts your requirements.
3. SignedTransaction is immutable object. And for new State to be committed into the ledger, all parties should sign the transaction. In any case Input, Output states will be visible for all parties. This point also contradicts with your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as of Corda 3.x.

Suppose we label:

- `State1` the input known only by A
- `State2` the output known only by B
- `State3` the output known by A and B

For A to store `State3`, they will have to be sent the entire transaction including `State1` and `State2`. For B to store `State2` and `State3`, they will have to be sent the entire transaction including `State1`. There is currently no support in the platform for storing states in a node's vault based only on a filtered transaction.